# Differentiation problem gives $2=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$ \begin{align}x^2&=x+x+\cdots\ (\text{$x$ times})\\ \implies \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x^2)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x)+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x)+\cdots \ (\text{$x$ times})\\ \implies 2x&=1+
1+\cdots \ (\text{$x$ times})\\ \implies 2x&= x \\ \implies 2&=1 \end{align}  $$

Which is obviously wrong. So, where am I wrong?

Comment: $x$ isn't a constant.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain?

Comment: How can you add something a variable time ?? I mean, the first line you've written is absurd in mathematics.

Comment: What if $x=\frac12?$  What does your equation mean?  What does it mean if $x=\sqrt2?$  If $x=\pi?$